# Is it possible to write a QuerySet method that modifies the dataset but delays evaluation (similar to prefetch_related)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm working on a QuerySet class that does something similar to `prefetch_related` but allows the query to link data that's in an unconnected database (basically, linking records from django apps's database to records in a legacy system, using a shared unique key, something along the links of:

```
class UserFoo(models.Model):
    ''' Uses the django database & can link to User model '''
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userfoo')
    foo_record = models.CharField(
        max_length=32, 
        db_column="foo",
        unique=True
    ) # uuid pointing to legacy db table

    @property
    def foo(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_foo'):
            self._foo = Foo.objects.get(uuid=self.foo_record)
        return self._foo

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, foo_obj):
        self._foo = foo_obj
```

and then

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    '''Uses legacy database'''
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=32) # uuid for Foo legacy db table
    …

    @property
    def user(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_user'):
            self._user = User.objects.get(userfoo__foo_record=self.uuid)
        return self._user

    @user.setter
    def user(self, user_obj):
        self._user = user_obj
```

Run normally, a query that matches 100 foos (each with, say, 1 user record) will end up requiring 101 queries: one to get the foos, and a hundred for each user record (by doing a look up for the user record by calling the `user` property on each food).

To get around this, I am making something *similar* to `prefetch_related` which pulls all of the matching records for a query by the key, which means I just need one additional query to get the remaining records.

My code looks something like this:

```
class FooWithUserQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def with_foo(self):
        qs = self._clone()
        foo_idx = {}
        for record in self.all():
            foo_idx.setdefault(record.uuid, []).append(record)
        users = User.objects.filter(
            userfoo__foo_record__in=foo_idx.keys()
        ).select_related('django','relations','here')
        user_idx = {}
        for user in users:
            user_idx[user.userfoo.foo_record] = user
        for fid, frecords in foo_idx.items():
            user = user_idx.get(fid)
            for frecord in frecords:
                if user:
                    setattr(frecord, 'user', user)
        return qs
```

This *works*, but any extra data saved to a `foo` is lost if the query is later modified — that is, if the queryset is re-ordered or filtered in any way.

I would like a way to create a method that does exactly what I am doing now, but waits until the moment that adjusts whenever the query is evaluated, so that `foo` records always have a User record.

Some notes:

- the example has been highly simplified. There are actually a lot of tables that link up to the legacy data, and so for example although there is a one-to-on relationship between Foo and User, there will be some cases where a queryset will have multiple Foo records with the same key.
- the legacy database is on a different server and server platform, so I can't link the two tables using a database server itself
- ideally I'd like the User data to be cached, so that even if the records are sorted or sliced I don't have to re-run the foo query a second time.

Basically, I don't know enough about the internals of how the lazy evaluation of querysets works in order to do the necessary coding. I have jumped back and forth on the [source code for django.db.models.query](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py) but it really is a fairly dense read and I'm hoping someone out there who's worked with this already can offer some pointers.